# JVM thread dump location

Tags: java, jvm

When I issue a `kill -3 <pid>` command to my Java program, it generates the thread dump on the console. How do I redirect this to a file?

Comment: OK thanks people. I figured it out. the kill -3 command was causing my jvm to write to STDOUT. I just added this to my java call 1>"path to a logfile" and got this to work.

Answer (score 23):

Two options:

**Run your Java application with stdout redirected**

```
java com.example.MyApp > out.txt
```

**Use `jstack` instead.**

The [jstack](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html) utility allows you to get a thread dump and send the output to the current console instead of the stdout of the Java application, allowing you to redirect it.

For example, if the PID of your Java application is 12345 (use the [jps](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html) utility to find it quickly):

```
jstack 12345 > threads.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

I usually use the [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) profiler, but [jvisualvm](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) is available from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

If you want details of all threads and other JVM details, try jconsole.

Answer (score 0):

Please append following JVM arguments to your application. Thread dump should be captured at dump.log.

```
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:LogFile=dump.log
```

Please note it does not redirect, but enables JVM diagnostic logging. So, there could be possible over head as well.

However, if you can have JDK in the environment, using jstack or jcmd ([jcmd is preferred with JDK 1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr016.html)), you can capture thread dump and redirect to a file.