# Hibernate & Tomcat - won't close socket

Tags: java, hibernate, sockets, tomcat, c3p0

When I keep sending http requests to my webserver, it stops responding and I'm stuck in a white screen saying, 'waiting for xxx'. It goes unresponsive.

Also I don't see any exception on stacktrace. I don't see any exception in catalina.out.

I think it has something to do with tomcat not closing socket connections.
This only happens when

```
$ cd /proc/{processID}/fd
$ ls -l | wc -l
```

returns value over 1000.
Almost everytime I hit refresh the return value of 'ls -l | wc -l' goes up !

And if I issue this command

```
$ ll
```

I see a lot of records like

```
lrwx------ 1 root root 64  5월 22 17:49 989 -> socket:[1018368]
lr-x------ 1 root root 64  5월 22 17:41 99 -> socket:[1017430]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64  5월 22 17:49 990 -> socket:[1018369]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64  5월 22 17:49 991 -> socket:[1018370]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64  5월 22 17:49 992 -> socket:[1018371]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64  5월 22 17:49 993 -> socket:[1018384]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64  5월 22 17:49 994 -> socket:[1018373]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64  5월 22 17:49 995 -> socket:[1018374]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64  5월 22 17:49 996 -> socket:[1018375]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64  5월 22 17:49 997 -> socket:[1018377]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64  5월 22 17:49 998 -> socket:[1018378]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64  5월 22 17:49 999 -> socket:[1018379]
```

I'm pretty sure it's not about my web application not returning(or not closing) its connections to the database.

I'm using MySQL and I've configured my.cfg

```
[mysqld]
wait-timeout=3
interactive-timeout=60
```

I can check it in mysql

```
mysql> select @@session.wait_timeout, @@global.wait_timeout;
+------------------------+-----------------------+
| @@session.wait_timeout | @@global.wait_timeout |
+------------------------+-----------------------+
|                     30 |                     3 |
+------------------------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Also if I issue

This is not a DNS issue. I can open the website on my webserver just fine.

```
netstat -tulpn
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8005       :::*                        LISTEN      21395/java
tcp        0      0 :::8009                     :::*                        LISTEN      21395/java
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      21395/java
```

Also

```
lsof -p 21395
```

show a lot of

```
java    21395 root  359u  sock                0,5      0t0   1379694 can't identify protocol
java    21395 root  360u  sock                0,5      0t0   1379696 can't identify protocol
java    21395 root  361u  sock                0,5      0t0   1379697 can't identify protocol
java    21395 root  362u  sock                0,5      0t0   1379700 can't identify protocol
java    21395 root  363u  sock                0,5      0t0   1379702 can't identify protocol
java    21395 root  364u  sock                0,5      0t0   1379703 can't identify protocol
java    21395 root  365u  sock                0,5      0t0   1379961 can't identify protocol
```

Where as I can see Tomcat's connections to MySQL like

```
java    21395 root  390u  IPv6            1380717      0t0       TCP cooingbee.co.kr:40026->cooingbee.co.kr:mysql (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    21395 root  391u  IPv6            1380718      0t0       TCP cooingbee.co.kr:40025->cooingbee.co.kr:mysql (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    21395 root  392u  IPv6            1380721      0t0       TCP cooingbee.co.kr:40028->cooingbee.co.kr:mysql (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

I've set ulimit also

```
]# ulimit -n 
4096
]#ulimit -Hn
65536
```

In my sysctl.conf, I've added these but still no luck.

```
kernel.shmmni = 4096
kernel.sem = 256 32000 100 128
fs.aio-max-nr = 1048576
fs.file-max = 6815744
net.core.rmem_default = 262144
net.core.rmem_max = 4194304
net.core.wmem_default = 262144
net.core.wmem_max = 1048586
```

Additional Information on my server environment

```
CentOS 5.x
Java 7
Tomcat6 / 7 (I've tested my webapp on both tomcat 6 and 7)
MySQL 5.5
web application uses Hibernate, c3p0, Spring DI, MVC
```

I've confirmed from the DBMS side that connections are not leaking by using

```
show processlist
```

Question

What are those 'sock can't identify protocol' ?

Why my tomcat goes unresponsive if I have more than a thousand records in 
/proc/{processID}/fd ?

What should I do to make it work smooth?

**EDIT 1**
I'll show you the code. FYI, I didn't design nor intended to use Hibernate and Spring this way. I think you'll see why I say this now ;).

part pf my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://***.***.***.***:3306/****</property>
<property name="connection.username">****</property>
<property name="connection.password">****</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">5</property> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10000</property> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout">70</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1</property>
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
```

part of my spring-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <!--  
        <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource"/></property>
        -->
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
```

Finally, some Java code

```
public class ItemDAOImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements ItemDAO {

public ItemDetail itemDetail(Integer itemSeq) { 
        ItemDetail itemDetail = null;

        try {
            itemDetail =  (ItemDetail) this.getHibernateTemplate().get("kr.co.sgis.services.web.mobile.item.form.ItemDetail", itemSeq);
            System.out.println("Item Detail~ :: " + itemDetail.getId());
            return itemDetail;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage() + "\nThe Stack Trace is:"); 
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return itemDetail;
        }

    }
public Item itemView(Integer itemSeq, Integer mo_id) { 
        Item itemView = null;
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = getSession(); 
            Criteria item = session.createCriteria(Item.class)
               .add(Restrictions.eq("id", itemSeq))
               .add(Restrictions.eq("mobile_id", mo_id));
            itemView = (Item) item.uniqueResult();

            //itemView =  (ItemHead) this.getHibernateTemplate().get("kr.co.sgis.services.web.mobile.item.form.Item", itemSeq);
            System.out.println("Item View~ :: " + itemView.getId());
            session.flush();
            return itemView;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage() + "\nThe Stack Trace is:"); 
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return itemView;
        }finally{
            HibernateUtil.tryCloseAll(session, null);
        }

    }
...
}
```

As far as I've searched on the internet, getHibernateTemplate() and HibernateDAOSupport are not recommended. Also if I use getHibernateTemplate(), I don't have to manually, explicitly close session but I got desparate so I added 'HibernateUtil.tryCloseAll()'.

Here

```
public static void tryCloseAll(Session s, Transaction t){

        try{

            if(t!=null){
                if(t.isActive()){
                    //?
                    t.commit();
                }

            }

            if(s!=null){
                if(s.isOpen()){
                    try{
                        s.flush();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println("Tried to close session and failed");
                    }
                }
            }


        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
```

**EDIT 2**
The following is the output of kill -QUIT PID

```
2013-05-23 17:26:10
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.21-b01 mixed mode):

"http-80-6" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000002ad3800 nid=0x357f in Object.wait() [0x00002b75db57d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000fab5c158> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:458)
    - locked <0x00000000fab5c158> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:484)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"http-80-5" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000002505800 nid=0x3577 in Object.wait() [0x00002b75db47c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000fab1a4a0> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:458)
    - locked <0x00000000fab1a4a0> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:484)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"http-80-4" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000002f6a800 nid=0x3576 in Object.wait() [0x00002b75db37b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000fab60f68> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:458)
    - locked <0x00000000fab60f68> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:484)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"http-80-3" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000036fd800 nid=0x3575 in Object.wait() [0x00002b75db27a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000fab61d68> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:458)
    - locked <0x00000000fab61d68> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:484)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"http-80-2" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000002ac2000 nid=0x3574 in Object.wait() [0x00002b75db179000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000fab1f2f0> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:458)
    - locked <0x00000000fab1f2f0> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:484)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"http-80-1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000028eb800 nid=0x3571 in Object.wait() [0x00002b75dae6e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000fab62188> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:458)
    - locked <0x00000000fab62188> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:484)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"TP-Monitor" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000000260d800 nid=0x356f in Object.wait() [0x00002b75dad6d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000fab19420> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$MonitorRunnable)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$MonitorRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:565)
    - locked <0x00000000fab19420> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$MonitorRunnable)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"TP-Processor4" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000002add000 nid=0x356e runnable [0x00002b75dac6c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:522)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:490)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.accept(ChannelSocket.java:311)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.acceptConnections(ChannelSocket.java:668)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketAcceptor.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:879)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"TP-Processor3" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000002adb800 nid=0x356d in Object.wait() [0x00002b75dab6b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000fab18d30> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:662)
    - locked <0x00000000fab18d30> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"TP-Processor2" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000025d9000 nid=0x356c in Object.wait() [0x00002b75daa6a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000fab18f80> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:662)
    - locked <0x00000000fab18f80> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"TP-Processor1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000025d8800 nid=0x356b in Object.wait() [0x00002b75da969000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000fab191d0> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:662)
    - locked <0x00000000fab191d0> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"http-80-Acceptor-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002b75dc769000 nid=0x356a runnable [0x00002b75da622000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:522)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:490)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.acceptSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:61)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000000424d000 nid=0x3569 waiting on condition [0x00002b75da521000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1631)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"Timer-1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000000267b000 nid=0x3564 in Object.wait() [0x00002b75da82c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c3046fb8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
    - locked <0x00000000c3046fb8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"Timer-0" prio=10 tid=0x00000000026c0800 nid=0x3563 in Object.wait() [0x00002b75da72b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c30906a0> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
    - locked <0x00000000c30906a0> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"GC Daemon" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002b75dc44d800 nid=0x3562 in Object.wait() [0x00002b75d9d98000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c29e3d38> (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)
    at sun.misc.GC$Daemon.run(GC.java:117)
    - locked <0x00000000c29e3d38> (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)

"Service Thread" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000002382000 nid=0x3560 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000002377000 nid=0x355f waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000002374000 nid=0x355e waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000002371800 nid=0x355d waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000002324800 nid=0x355c in Object.wait() [0x00002b75d5832000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c287dbd8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x00000000c287dbd8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:189)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000000231d000 nid=0x355b in Object.wait() [0x00002b75d5731000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c287d7f8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
    - locked <0x00000000c287d7f8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=10 tid=0x0000000002284000 nid=0x3551 runnable [0x00002b75cc81a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:522)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:431)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:676)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:628)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0000000002315800 nid=0x355a runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000002291800 nid=0x3552 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000002293800 nid=0x3553 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000002295000 nid=0x3554 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000002297000 nid=0x3555 runnable 

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000002299000 nid=0x3556 runnable 

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000000000229a800 nid=0x3557 runnable 

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000000000229c800 nid=0x3558 runnable 

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000000000229e800 nid=0x3559 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x000000000238c800 nid=0x3561 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 232

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 197248K, used 65894K [0x00000000eb760000, 0x00000000fbb30000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 180608K, 27% used [0x00000000eb760000,0x00000000ee781540,0x00000000f67c0000)
  from space 16640K, 99% used [0x00000000faaf0000,0x00000000fbb28510,0x00000000fbb30000)
  to   space 26368K, 0% used [0x00000000f87b0000,0x00000000f87b0000,0x00000000fa170000)
 ParOldGen       total 76864K, used 45414K [0x00000000c2600000, 0x00000000c7110000, 0x00000000eb760000)
  object space 76864K, 59% used [0x00000000c2600000,0x00000000c5259a10,0x00000000c7110000)
 PSPermGen       total 67200K, used 44249K [0x00000000bd400000, 0x00000000c15a0000, 0x00000000c2600000)
  object space 67200K, 65% used [0x00000000bd400000,0x00000000bff36788,0x00000000c15a0000)
```

Comment: have you used jstack or an old-fashioned ctrl-\ to get a dump of if/where your client-handling threads seem to be hung?

Comment: pardon my ignorance, I've never heard of jstack nor got any knowledge of ' ctrl-\ '. Jstack seems out of service. Could you elabourate a little please ?

Comment: see e.g. http://helpx.adobe.com/cq/kb/TakeThreadDump.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062493/jvm-thread-dump-location note pressing ctrl-\ (UNIX or MacOS, ctrl-break in Windows) in the console where your app is running is the same as running kill -QUIT on the process. you can also use VisualVM to get a thread dump

Comment: see http://helpx.adobe.com/cq/kb/TakeThreadDump.html or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062493/jvm-thread-dump-location not that typing ctrl-\ (UNIX/Mac, ctrl-break WIN) is equivalent to sending kill -QUIT to the running process. you can also get thread dumps via the snazzy (and free) VisualVM http://visualvm.java.net/

Comment: Thank you very much! I can use this in the future. I got the thread dump but it's too long. Could you tell me what sort of things I should be looking for  in the output ?

Comment: I've also managed to put the whole output of the command kill -QUIT. See Edit 2

Comment: so notice that none of these threads have even hit your software. there's nothing in your code, or hibernate, or c3p0, or your jdbc driver. there are threads waiting to handle http requests, tomcat threads listening on sockets to accept requests, etc. so, what you've learned is where not to look. the problem is not in your application code or the middleware beneath it. requests don't seem to get so far. the issue is at the network and/or the tomcat level. you don't know what the problem is, but it helps a bit to know what it isnt...

Comment: (note: hopefully that stack trace dump was taken immediately after you've made a request that is hanging! that is, you want to sample your JVM when any hang inside the code you control is most likely to be present! if you just took a sample of your broken tomcat instance at an arbitrary moment, hit it with some client requests and sample again while it is actively hanging.)

Comment: I've just changed the way entities are associated(from Annotation to XML) and I see way less number of connections. Hope this helps someone who's having similar problem. I haven't completely solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You posted a lot of terrific information, but no code.

It might be overkill to do so now.

Are you using a connection pool?    Did you set up JNDI data sources in Tomcat, or are you acquiring connections in your code using Hibernate?  In either case, are you sure that you're closing your connections properly when you're done with them?  That should be done in a finally block after the unit of work is committed or rolled back.

Hibernate appears to be a problem.  What's it buying you?

I think you'd be better off with an interface-based DAO with a Spring JDBC implementation.

If you're using an Oracle/Sun JVM, you can also attach [Visual VM](http://visualvm.java.net/download.html) to your Tomcat PID and let it tell you what's going on.  It'll show you memory generations, threads, CPU, object creation - all in real time.

Comment: Thx, I'll have your opinion as the last resort but I don't think I can change the way the app accesses database through out the entire app. 'What's it buying you?' You mean why I use Hibernate ? to use O-R mapping.

Comment: Yes, that's what everyone says.  They all think that O/R is going to be a great savings - until it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got this working somehow. I'll try and describe as much as I can.
First of all, what seemed to have changed the number of open session was going from Annotation to XML in Hibernate configuration. 
Also I think the datasource declared in spring xml overrides other configuration in hibernate.cfg.xml. I added connection pooling configuration to the datasource in the spring servlet xml.

Hope this may give you a clue if you are having the same kind of problem.